# Remove character range from string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

i am creating a function in java script to remove some characters from string i tried string.slice()
string.substr()
string.substring() but i want to 
remove everything before colon **:**

its not decided whats the length of person name

i want result like

this is test text1

this is test text2

this is test text3

this is test text4

some time text is like (**Qt: john: when i said .... she: not again**),in this case i want result would be (**when i said .... she: not again**)
i just want to remove (Qt: name:) what ever written after that i want as it is.

```
function myFunction() {
  var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
  var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
  var c="this is test text3";
  var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";
  removetxt(a);
  removetxt(b);
  removetxt(c);
  removetxt(d);
}

function removetxt(x){
  if (x.slice(0,2) == 'Qt'){
    console.log("found Qt");
  }else
     console.log(x);      
}
```

Comment: Use a regex, something as `x.replace(/^.+: ?/g, "")`

Comment: i tried it but some time text is like (Qt: john: when i said .... she: not again), now if i use this regex i will get only (not again) hope you got what i wanna say

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Do you want to remove chars from a string or find a substring?

Comment: i just wanna remove that (Qt: name:)  all i want is what ever written after that

Comment: Try this: `var removeTxt = x => x.replace(/^.+: ?/g, "");`. And so it is invoked: `removeTxt("Qt: bella: this is test text2")`

Comment: no i want `when i said .... she: not again` this as result not only `not again`

Comment: @faysal there is an update to my solution waiting since yesterday, that does what you back than did describe more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction() {
  var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
  var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
  var c="this is test text3";
  var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";
  removetxt(a);
  removetxt(b);
  removetxt(c);
  removetxt(d);
}

function removetxt(x){
  var y = x.split(':');

  if (y[0] == 'Qt'){
    console.log("found Qt");
  }else
     console.log(y);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Replace(str, find, replaceWith) {
if (find === replaceWith)
    return str;
do
{
    str = str.replace(find, replaceWith);
} 
 while(str.indexOf(find) !== -1);
return str;
}

var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
var qt = "Qt:";
```

Now call the function like this:

```
Replace(a, "Qt:", "");
```

The result is:

```
joe: this is test text1
```

Comment: yep but i wanna remove that name also, (Qt: name:) all i want is what ever written after that

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
    var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
    var c="this is test text3";
    var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";

    extractTextAfterLastColon(a);
    extractTextAfterLastColon(b);
    extractTextAfterLastColon(c);
    extractTextAfterLastColon(d);
}

function extractTextAfterLastColon(str){
    var // any non colon character sequence that reaches the end.
        regX   = (/([^:]+)$/),
        result = regX.exec(str),

        text   = result && result[1].trim();

    console.log(text);      
}

myFunction();
```

> OP: bro i update my question and explain my problem in more details, your function does same what i can get from x.replace(/^.+: ?/g, "")

Now that puts a new perspective onto it - the solution then is the same, but the RegExp gains more complexity.

```
function myFunction() {
    var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
    var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
    var c="this is test text3";
    var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";
    var e="Qt: john: when i said .... she: not again";

    extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(a);
    extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(b);
    extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(c);
    extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(d);
    extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(e);
}

function extractTextAfterQuestionOrProtagonist(str) {
    var
        regX   = (/(?:qt\:\s*(?:[^\s:]+:\s*)*)(.*)$/i),
        result = regX.exec(str),

        text   = ((result && result[1]) || str).trim();

    console.log(text);      
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: bro i update my question and explain my problem in more details, your function does same what i can get from `x.replace(/^.+: ?/g, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
$(function(){
  var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
  var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
  var c="this is test text3";
  var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";
  removetxt(a);
  removetxt(b);
  removetxt(c);
  removetxt(d);
});

function removetxt(x){
  var y = x.split(':');

  if (y.length > 1){
    alert(y[y.length-1])
  }else
     alert(y[0]);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            myFunction()
            function myFunction() {
              var a="Qt: joe: this is test text1";
              var b="Qt: bella: this is test text2";
              var c="this is test text3";
              var d="Qt: alex: this is test text4";
              removetxt(a);
              removetxt(b);
              removetxt(c);
              removetxt(d);
            }
            function removetxt(x) {
               var x1 = x.replace(/^(Qt:.*:)/g,"");
                alert(x1);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, if you can guarantee at least two colons or none, the following will work:

```
var temp=yourStr.substr(yourStr.indexOf(":")+1);
 //if indexOf=-1, whole str returned
temp=temp.substr(temp.indexOf(":")+1);
var yourNewStr=temp;
```